# Recursion Logical Error Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have this assignment for school and it wants me to use recursion. I'm new to recursion and I understand it but I just can't figure out why this method isn't working the way it's suppose to. These are the instructions that were given to me[image: This is the picture] and this is my code

```
// This method will be completed by the student!
  // The student should implement the binary search algorithm using recursion.  The
  // method will originally be called by the GUI logic when the Search button is clicked.
    public int binarySearch(Integer[] targetArray, int targetValue, int lowIndex, int highIndex){
        if (lowIndex > highIndex)
          return -1;
        int midIndex = lowIndex + (highIndex - lowIndex)/2;
        if (targetValue == targetArray[midIndex])
          return midIndex;
        if(targetArray[midIndex] > targetValue)
          binarySearch(targetArray, targetValue, lowIndex, midIndex - 1);
        else if(targetArray[midIndex] < targetValue)
          binarySearch(targetArray, targetValue, midIndex + 1, highIndex);
        return -1; // replace this with your recursive binary search code
      }
```

The program will ask the user to enter in a target value. It will then search an array using recursion to tell if the target value is in the array. The array holds the numbers {1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15}. When I search for the number 5 a message box pops up and says "Number 5 not found!" but when I set the target value to 8 it finds it in the array

Comment: Can you provide a testcase where your code is not working?

Comment: By testcase do you mean where I run the code and the output is something that is incorrect?

Comment: yes indeed. Provide a sample case of input together with the expected output and the computed output.

Comment: Use the debugger, Luke!

Comment: I updated the post to tell what the input and output is of some test runs and Boris I'm using Dr. Java and it doesn't have a debugger :/ I wish it did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have figured out the solution. The if-else statement was suppose to return the values at the end.

```
public int binarySearch(Integer[] targetArray, int targetValue, int lowIndex, int highIndex){
    if (lowIndex > highIndex)
      return -1;
    int midIndex = lowIndex + (highIndex - lowIndex)/2;
    if (targetValue == targetArray[midIndex])
      return midIndex;
    if(targetArray[midIndex] > targetValue)
      return binarySearch(targetArray, targetValue, lowIndex, midIndex - 1);
    else //if(targetArray[midIndex] < targetValue)
      return binarySearch(targetArray, targetValue, midIndex + 1, highIndex);
    //return -1; // replace this with your recursive binary search code
  }
```

Comment: Correct. Ending the recursive statement with a hard return of -1 means that no matter what path you get every call that hits the final `else if` is going to return -1 even if the result was found.

Answer (score 1):

I take it the comment stems from the review?

```
public int binarySearch(int[] targetArray, int targetValue,
        int lowIndex, int highIndex) {
    if (lowIndex > highIndex)
      return -1;
    int midIndex = lowIndex + (highIndex - lowIndex)/2;
    if (targetValue == targetArray[midIndex])
      return midIndex;
    if (targetArray[midIndex] > targetValue)
      return binarySearch(targetArray, targetValue, lowIndex, midIndex - 1);
    else //if(targetArray[midIndex] < targetValue)
      return binarySearch(targetArray, targetValue, midIndex + 1, highIndex);
  }
```

The solution is to remove the last else-if.

Also you did not return the results of the recursively found index.

(An `int[]` parameter instead of `Integer[]` would be better.)

Also normally (99% of the) programmers use `{}` with `if`.

Comment: I have commented the if part of the last else if and I commented the return -1 at the end but since it doesn't have a return type at the end it throws an error. So I put the return -1 back and it still has the same results

Comment: As you do not return the recursive return values, for recursive findings -1 (the last return) is returned.

Comment: The method, method parameters and the return -1 were pre-typed by the course itself. I was given the task of filling in the body

Comment: That `return -1;` one probably rights substituting. Probably was a placeholder for being compilable. Alternatively you could do `if (lowIndex <= highIndex) { ... } return -1;`

Comment: The main point is that the result of the recursive call should be used as result. You are doing the main function, and send a clone of yourself for the rest of the work. If the clone comes back it makes sense to use the clone's results for yourself.